# Reactstrap form validation confusion

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I have been working on forms lately. I am trying to add validation to my existing form. I am using a reducer and using Form from reactstrap.

This setup uses a class component **BUT** does not use a  reducer: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-fancy-forms-reactstrap.  In a nutshell, they call a function on the onChange event of a form field that does some logic to determine whether the value entered is valid or not.

That's great for one field. In my case I have 9 on this particular form. I was looking at this post and it seems pretty close to what I need to implement but all their stuff is on one page - no reducer: [How to know the state of input/form fields of reactstrap form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892154/how-to-know-the-state-of-input-form-fields-of-reactstrap-form).

So this is how I was starting off:

**State initialization**

```
const initialState = {
  //form fields
  companyId: "",
  companyName: "",
  website: "",
  fiscalYearEnd: "",
  taxIDNumber: "",
  companyTypeID: "",
  isKeyCompany: "",
  databaseName: "",
  statusID: "",
  //other data needed in the state
  companyMasterData: [],
  errorAlertVisible: false,
  formVisible: true,
  companyMasterAdded: false,
  // requiredInputState: "",
}

const CompanyMasterAdd = () => {
  
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, initialState)
  const [requiredInputState, setRequiredInputState] = useState("good")
  const history = useHistory()
```

**Form stuff**

```
       <Form onSubmit={addCompanyMaster} id="companyMasterForm">
          <FormGroup row>
            <Label for="companyId" sm={2}>
              CompanyId
            </Label>
            <Col sm={2}>
              <Input
                type="text"
                name="companyId"
                value={state.companyId || ""}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleInputChange(e)
                  validateInput("companyId", e)
                }}
                invalid={requiredInputState === "bad"}
                
              ></Input>
              <FormFeedback>CompanyId is required</FormFeedback>
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup row>
            <Label for="companyName" sm={2}>
              CompanyName
            </Label>
            <Col sm={2}>
              <Input
                id="companyName"
                type="text"
                name="companyName"
                value={state.companyName || ""}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleInputChange(e)
                  validateInput("companyName", e)
                }}
                invalid={requiredInputState === "bad"}
              ></Input>
              <FormFeedback>CompanyName is required</FormFeedback>
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
```

**1st (of many?) Validation methods**

```
function validateInput(inputName, e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    switch (inputName) {
      case "statusID":
      case "databaseName":
      case "companyName":
      case "companyId":
        if (!e.target.value) {
          setRequiredInputState("bad")
        } else {
          setRequiredInputState("good")
        }
      // dispatch({
      //   type: INPUT_VALIDATION,
      //   field: e.target.name,

      //   payload: e.target.value,
      // })

      default:
        break
    }
  }
```

Calling functions to set various types of fields seems like it could get messy really quickly. I feel like it's a hack of sorts doing it this way.  I thought the reducer was supposed to handle all of the state stuff. I'm confused on how to implement form validation of field inputs at this point. Am I supposed to use a combination of the reducer as well as some logic in useState to validate the fields?

**Technically this works**

```
  const [databaseNameValid, setDatabaseName] = useState("valid")
  const [statusIDValid, setStatusIDValid] = useState("valid")
  const history = useHistory()
  const handleInputChange = (input) => {
    dispatch({
      type: INPUT_TEXT_CHANGE_HANDLED,
      field: input.target.name,
      payload: input.target.value,
    })
    validateInput(input.target.name, input.target.value)
  }

  function validateInput(inputName, inputValue) {
    inputValue.preventDefault

    switch (inputName) {
      case "companyId":
        //if there is no value present for a required field then set the field as invalid
        !inputValue ? setCompanyIdValid("invalid") : setCompanyIdValid("valid")
        break
      case "companyName":
        !inputValue
          ? setCompanyNameValid("invalid")
          : setCompanyNameValid("valid")
        break
      case "databaseName":
        !inputValue ? setDatabaseName("invalid") : setDatabaseName("valid")
        break
      case "statusID":
        !inputValue ? setStatusIDValid("invalid") : setStatusIDValid("valid")
        break

      default:
        break
    }
  }
```

I just feel like it's an ugly way to do it and I feel there must be a better way